# Inserting Session Email into MySQL table using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, session, insert

### MySQL table 'users' structure:

```
 id  |  user_name | user_pass  | user_email |
 1   |  anderson  |  password  |boy@mail.com|
```

---

**MySQL table 'history' structure:**

---

```
 id  |  user_email  |
 1   | boy@mail.com |  <<< trying to insert boy@mail.com under user_email
```

## trying to insert boy@mail into the 'history' table under user_email

Hi, I made two tables in MySQL database. The first is called users and the second is called history. I have a login and registration PHP code that allows users to register and login using the 'users' table. When I login, the page redirects me to a welcome page with my user_email displayed using a $_SESSION  which look like this  .

Now I would like to do the following; If the user has logged in, insert the $_SESSION['email'] into the 'history' table under user_email.

I've got this code, and I know it really wrong. But I'm new to php. So can someone help me fix it and insert the Session data from the first table into the second table, only if user is logged in. Thanks a lot!

======================================================================
MY-CODE: for trying to insert session value into 'history' table

```
<head>
                          <?php 
                                     session_start();   
                                    $_SESSION['email'];         
                                   $query = "insert into history (email) values ('$email')";
                             ?>     


</head>
```

Comment: use the $_SESSIOn... then do a select query get the email where $_SESSION then do the insert query.

Comment: You mean $email = $_SESSION['email'];?

Comment: But u r not defining $email = $_SESSION ['email']

Comment: plus, you're also not executing the query. Hard to say if you're even connecting to db and which MySQL API used with it, making it all that much unclear and harder to give a concrete answer. You're also outputting before header with the position of `session_start();`

Comment: also, why do you have SQL in head?

Comment: good luck, moving on.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys. Yes I have connected to database. Everything is working. I just need to insert the session [email] from user into history. so that i know where a user has logged in. But i am not sure how to insert he session value into another table :(

Comment: @shehary be my guest ;-)

Comment: Shehary, I tired what you suggested ;s it still did not insert into the history table :(.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['login'])){
 
 $password = $_POST['pass'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 
 $check_user = "select * from users where user_pass='$password' AND user_email='$email'";
 
 $run = mysql_query($check_user);
 
 if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){
  
  $_SESSION['email']=$email;
  
  $query = "insert into history (user_email) values ('$email')";
  echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
   }
  else {
   
   echo "<script>alert('Email or password x ')</script>";
   
  }
}

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works perfectly XD

Comment: @zzas11 Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OP provided very vague detail, Can suggest following solution, which is very much achieveable with very less hassel

As OP mentioned in question "I have a login and registration PHP code that allows users to register and login using the 'users' table. When I login, the page redirects me to a welcome page"

on your login page, where you can check the user-name and password and after validation, you redirect the user to welcome page, before redirection and after validation run this insert query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO history (user_email) VALUES ('$email')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

on very same page. Don't forget to define `$email` variable First
no need of `$_SESSION['email'];`
no need to write new query
no need of extra coding

Update;
OP provided the code in comment

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $check_user = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_pass='$password' AND user_email='$email'";
        $run = mysql_query($check_user);
        $row= mysql_fetch_array($check_user);
        $email = $row['user_email'];

        if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0){
            $_SESSION['email']=$email; //If you don't need this, remove this
            $query = "INSERT INTO history (user_email) values ('$email')";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
        echo "<script>window.open('welcome.php','_self')</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Email or password x ')</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: good show. However, best to store a hash and not plain text for passwords ;-) let's hope OP is using safe password hashing

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for your help!! and dont worry :) I wont use plain texts haha, but for now Just keeping everything simple for testing purposes XD.